# VBA function returning '#VALUE!'

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, mode

```
Public Function MostOccuring(items() As Variant) As String
    Dim count() As Integer
    Dim strings() As Object
    Dim Index As Integer
    For Index = 0 To items.Length - 1
        If srings.Exists(items(Index)) Then
            count(strings.IndexOf(items(Index))) = 1 + count(strings.IndexOf(items(Index)))
        Else
            count(Index) = 1
            strings(Index) = items(Index)
        End If
    Next
    End
    MostOccuring = strings(count.IndexOf(count.Max()))

End Function
```

This is my mostocurring function
[image: This is how I call it]

This is how I call it

And it return '#VALUE!'. Why? It should return the most occuring string of the cells. Thanks.

Comment: `If srings.Exists(items(Index))` should be `If strings.Exists(items(Index))`. Above all your code, above the `Sub` put `Option Explicit` and it will keep these mistakes from happening.

Comment: Exactly what is the `MostOccuring` statement at the top, supposed to be doing? Seems to me this would be an illegal statement. If your code doesn't compile (Debug > Compile VBProject), it surely won't run.

Comment: this can be done with existing functions: `=INDEX(C:C,MODE(MATCH(C2:C10,C:C,0)))`

Comment: To help diagnose these things, it helps to toss a breakpoint on lines so the code stops on that line while executing allowing you to inspect your variable's values in the "Locals" pane of VBE.

Comment: ...or call your function from a Sub so you can more easily debug it

Comment: First of all remove `MostOccuring` line, it rise a runtime error due to parameter is missing, that is why the function returns `#VALUE!`

Comment: First of all remove `MostOccuring` line, it rise a runtime error due to arbitrary parameter is missing, that is why the function returns `#VALUE!`

Answer (score 0):

You may also try something like this...

```
Public Function MostOccuring(items As Range) As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim dict, it
Dim maxCnt As Long

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each cell In items
    If Not dict.exists(cell.Value) Then
        dict.Item(cell.Value) = 1
    Else
        dict.Item(cell.Value) = dict.Item(cell.Value) + 1
    End If
Next cell

For Each it In dict.keys
    If dict.Item(it) > maxCnt Then
        maxCnt = dict.Item(it)
        MostOccuring = it
    End If
Next it
End Function
```